# Selecting multiple rows based on column value, then dividing two column values with eachother and multiplying them in R

Tags: r, row, division, multiplication

I'm new to R so please bear with me! I Have a dataframe named `mydata`. Here's a sample of the relevant columns:

```
Backlog.Item.Type       State Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate Task.Completed.Hours
                Epic In Progress                          NA                   NA
             Feature         New                          NA                   NA
Product Backlog Item        Done                          NA                   NA
                Task        Done                        5.00                 0.50
                Task        Done                        3.00                 0.50
                Task        Done                        5.50                 6.50
                Task        Done                        2.50                 3.00
                Task        Done                        2.00                 5.50
                Task        Done                        2.00                 3.00
Product Backlog Item        Done                          NA                   NA
Product Backlog Item        Done                          NA                   NA
Product Backlog Item    Approved                          NA                   NA
                Task In Progress                          NA                   NA
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is the following: I want to select the rows where the value for `Backlog.Item.Type` = Task, `State` = Done and `Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate` & `Task.Completed.Hours` are not N/A or 0.00. Once the rows that meet these conditions have been selected, I want to perform the following calculation on them: `Task.Completed.Hours` / (divided by) `Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate` x (multiplied by) 100. I then want to store this new value in a new column and calculate the mean of this entire column. Thanks in advance, I hope I have been clear enough and formulated my question in a understandable manner!

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `logical` vector where `TRUE` indicates that the sample is of your interest and `FALSE` that it is not.
It is difficult to build the correct code without having acces to the data but I will try to help you (considering `data` is the name of the matrix you show).

```
# Build the logical vector (according to what you mentioned)
   # First condition
     cond1 <- data$Backlog.Item.Type == "Task"
   # Second condition
     cond2 <- !data$Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate %in% c("NA", 0)
   # Third condition
     cond3 <- !data$Task.Completed.Hours %in% c("NA",0)
   # The final logical vector can be computed
     l <- as.logical(cond1*cond2*cond3)

# Take the subset of samples satisfying the three conditions
  sub.data <- data[l,]

# The new value
  new <- 100*sub.data$Task.Completed.Hours/sub.data$Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate

# Add new into tha table
  sub.data$new <- new
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I appreciate the way you structured this, it really helped me in understanding how to tackle a problem like this :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- mydata %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(Backlog.Item.Type=="Task" & 
         State=="Done" & 
         Task.Completed.Hours>0) %>% 
  mutate(new_var=Task.Completed.Hours/Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate*100)
```

output is:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Backlog.Item.Type State Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate Task.Completed.Hours    new_var
  <chr>             <chr>                       <dbl>                <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Task              Done                         5.00                0.500    10.0
2 Task              Done                         3.00                0.500    16.7
3 Task              Done                         5.50                6.50    118  
4 Task              Done                         2.50                3.00    120  
5 Task              Done                         2.00                5.50    275  
6 Task              Done                         2.00                3.00    150
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the perfect and elegant solution Stephan! I just have a final noobie question for you: how do I add the `new_var` column from the new `result` dataframe to my `mydata` dataframe?

Comment: So you want the `na` values also in your DF from the combinations that are not filtered?

Comment: mydata <- left_join(mydata, result, by = "ID") did the trick! Thanks again Stephan :)

Answer (score 0):

You did mention in your question that you're getting warmed on R, but still, it would be useful for everyone if you show your trials to the problem.

There is a good resource on how to subset (select rows or columns based on your requirements) dataframes [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

Now, assume that `df` is your data frame.
In R, the dataframes are subsetted in the following format :

```
df[ROWs,COLUMNs]
```

While you can pass row/column numbers inside the square brackets to subset the dataframe, one very useful method is to use logical vectors.

Eg:

```
df <- mtcars
#Create a logical vector to subset rows
logical_vector <- df$mpg > 20
#Use logical_vector to subset df
df[logical_vector,]
```

This would select all the rows where mileage per gallon is greater than 20.

On to your problem :

You should create a logical vector first which handles all your conditions :

```
####CONDITIONS
cond1_vec <- df$Backlog.Item.Type == "Task"
cond2_vec <- df$State == "Done"
#Next condition should check that Task.Completed.Hours is NOT empty OR 0.
cond3_vec <- (!is.na(df$Task.Completed.Hours) | df$Task.Completed.Hours != 0)
#Next condition should check that Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate is NOT empty OR 0.
cond4_vec <- (!is.na(df$Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate) | df$Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate != 0)


####SUBSETTING
#Now, select only those rows which satisfy ALL of the above conditions
#That's why we join the conditions using AND (&)
row_select_vector <-  cond1_vec & cond2_vec & cond3_vec & cond4_vec

#Use the method of subsetting dataframes using logical vectors
df_selected <- df[row_select_vector,]


####NEW COLUMN
#Now create a new column which gives the quotient of Hours by Estimate
df_selected$Ratio <- df_selected$Task.Completed.Hours / df_selected$Task.Initial.Hours.Estimate


####FINAL CALCULATION
#Calculate mean
ratio_mean <- mean(df_selected$Ratio)
```

Few things to note:

1. `is.na()` is used to check whether a field is NA. It's incorrect to do `df$field == NA`
2. You can keep all the conditions grouped together in the row field while subsetting. But it's much more legible to create a different logical vector when you have many conditions to check.
3. Checkout the `subset()` function in R - You might find it easier.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dave! Considering I have a lot of analyzing to do, I'm certain I will be encountering problems such as described in my question many more times. Your answer definitely helped me with understanding how I should go about it from now on, thanks again! (Sadly I can't upvote you as a beginner :()